# display special prices in excel sheet which displaying in site using catalog price rules

Tags: price, special-price

we have uploaded about 1000 products in a site.

we used "catalog price rules" to give discount for all products,

so special prices are displaying in site.

we want to get all those special prices in a excel sheet

when i use "export all products", special prices are not displaying in excel sheet in .csv format.

is there any option to display "special prices" in exc el sheet which we gave specail prices by applying

catalog price rules?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate action in a controller that will retrieve the products with special prices and export them in a csv format.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('discount', '(price_index.price - price_index.min_price)', array());
$products->getSelect()->having('discount > 0');

$pricesBySku = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
     $pricesBySku[$product->getSku()] = $product->getDiscount();
}
//do what every you want with $pricesBySku. export it as a csv, print it on the screen...
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Marius, 

 what steps i have to follow to create separate action in controller.

can you please tell me in which file i have to add this code

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on the web on how to create your own controller. A simple search got me to this one for example: http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller

Comment: okay @Marius i will try that tutorial , thanks again for your support....